# Duplicate record moved to other dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

A dataframe has 3 million records. i am trying to move only duplicate records to seperate dataframe.
**I am using spark 1.6 with scala**
Data

```
IM,A-15ACWSSC,CP
IM,A-15ACWSSC,CP
IM,AK11-130BA,13MM BLK RUBBER CAB
```

New DataFrame

```
IM,A-15ACWSSC,CP
IM,A-15ACWSSC,CP
```

Code i have used

```
var df = Seq(
      ("IM", "A-15ACWSSC", "ASSY 1.5V2", "CP"),
      ("IM", "A-15ACWSSC", "ASSY 1.5V2", "CP"),
      ("IN", "A-15ACWSSC", "ASSY 1.6V2", "CP1"),
      ("IN", "A-15ACWSSC", "ASSY 1.7V2", "CP2")
    ).toDF("COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4")

    df.show()

    // +----+----------+----------+----+
    // |COL1|      COL2|      COL3|COL4|
    // +----+----------+----------+----+
    // |  IM|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.5V2|  CP|
    // |  IM|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.5V2|  CP|
    // |  IN|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.6V2| CP1|
    // |  IN|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.7V2| CP2|
    // +----+----------+----------+----+

    df.registerTempTable("CLEANFRAME")

    val CleanData = sqlContext.sql(
      """select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
                              from
                              (SELECT  COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, count(1) over (partition by COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) as Uniqueid
                              FROM CLEANFRAME)
                              where Uniqueid > 1
                              """).cache()
    CleanData.show
```

But it is not giving any result. Please help if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should be modified as below. Every columns should be included in group by.

**Edit** : Used windowing and duplicates records are preserved.

```
 var df = Seq(
       ("IM","A-15ACWSSC","ASSY 1.5V2","CP"),
       ("IM","A-15ACWSSC","ASSY 1.5V2","CP"),
       ("IN","A-15ACWSSC","ASSY 1.6V2","CP1"),
       ("IN","A-15ACWSSC","ASSY 1.7V2","CP2")
   ).toDF("COL1", "COL2","COL3","COL4")

 df.show()

 // +----+----------+----------+----+
 // |COL1|      COL2|      COL3|COL4|
 // +----+----------+----------+----+
 // |  IM|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.5V2|  CP|
 // |  IM|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.5V2|  CP|
 // |  IN|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.6V2| CP1|
 // |  IN|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.7V2| CP2|
 // +----+----------+----------+----+


 df.createOrReplaceTempView("CLEANFRAME")

val CleanData= sqlContext.sql("""select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
                                  from 
                                  (SELECT  COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, count(1) over (partition by COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) as Uniqueid
                                  FROM CLEANFRAME)
                                  where Uniqueid > 1
                                  """ ).cache()
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.79] failure: ``)'' expected but `(' found

                                  (SELECT  COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, count(1) over (partition by COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) as Uniqueid
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, but it is throwing error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.79] failure: ``)'' expected but `(' found

                                  (SELECT  COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, count(1) over (partition by COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) as Uniqueid

Comment: Can you share the spark sql query here.

Comment: i have edited the code in question. please help..... Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Manish, i have shared the code in question itself. Kindly suggest

Comment: Can you try the below in spark sql  :-

"""select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
                              from
                              (SELECT  COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, count(1) over (partition by COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) as Uniqueid
                              FROM CLEANFRAME) a where Uniqueid > 1"""



note: alias is added after nested query

Comment: Same error. Does Spark 1.6 support partition function, not sure. Please help

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.76] failure: ``)'' expected but `(' found

select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 from (SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4, count(1) over (partition by COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) as Uniqueid FROM CLEANFRAME) a where Uniqueid > 1

Comment: Windowing is allowed in spark only with hive context.Please try this this query
select a.COL1,a.COL2,a.COL3,a.COL4 
                                 from CLEANFRAME a inner join 
                                 (SELECT  COUNT(1) as unique_ID,
                                         COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
                                  FROM CLEANFRAME
                                  GROUP BY COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
                                  HAVING unique_ID > 1) b 
                                  on a.COL1 = b.COL1 and a.COL2 = b.COL2 and a.COL3 = b.COL3 and a.COL4 = b.COL4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200816/discussion-between-rohini-mathur-and-manish).

Answer (score 0):

> you can try this

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
scala> var win = Window.partitionBy("a","b","c","d").orderBy("a")

scala> var dff = Seq(("IM","A-15ACWSSC","ASSY 1.5V2","CP"), ("IM","A-15ACWSSC","ASSY 1.5V2","CP"), ("IM","AK11-130BA","13MM BLK RUBBER CAB FOOT","ap")).toDF("a","b","c","d")

scala> dff.show
+---+----------+--------------------+---+
|  a|         b|                   c|  d|
+---+----------+--------------------+---+
| IM|A-15ACWSSC|          ASSY 1.5V2| CP|
| IM|A-15ACWSSC|          ASSY 1.5V2| CP|
| IM|AK11-130BA|13MM BLK RUBBER C...| ap|
+---+----------+--------------------+---+
for finding duplicates and based on that filter whose value is >= 2

scala> var dff_dup = dff.withColumn("test",count("*").over(win)).filter($"test">=2)


scala> dff_dup.show
+---+----------+----------+---+----+
|  a|         b|         c|  d|test|
+---+----------+----------+---+----+
| IM|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.5V2| CP|   2|
| IM|A-15ACWSSC|ASSY 1.5V2| CP|   2|
+---+----------+----------+---+----+
```

Comment: it is throwing error as Could not resolve window function 'count'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext; any idea how to enable hive support in spark 1.6